# Change document root for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am testing new codeigniter version 4, but after installing it, i am facing an error like this:

> If you see this message, you have not configured your web server
>   properly.
>
> You need to set your "document root" to the public folder inside your
>   project. This could be your default setting, or that of a virtual
>   host,  depending on how you set up your local development environment.

So how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Go to the application folder, then config folder and edit `config.php`?

Comment: I downloaded the codeignter 4 to a folder named ci4dev and kept it under htdocs. when I pointed to http://localhost/ci4dev/public I can see the debug page. See that it now uses public. I then read the doc and saw that I need to edit the application/Config/App.php file and set  public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/ci4dev/'; but it is not working as intended

Answer (score 0):

From their doc

> Open the **application/Config/App.php** file with a text editor and
>   set your base URL.

Comment: it is not working, actualling the information in question exists in index.html page at root folder of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Go to and open Xampp>>htdocs>>ci4dev>>Application>>Config>>App.php.

and edit the base URL line like 
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/ci4dev/public';

it works.

Comment: I don't see xampp mentioned in the OP ;) Also some explaination would help.

Comment: in my case i m using Xampp there is htdocs, if you using Wamp or Lamp or other http server you have to navigate to project directory.